# IF ELSE statement in Teradata

Tags: sql, if-statement, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two sql statements SQL 1 & SQL 2. Further, I want to run them as per below logic,

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COL1 > 0;

If ACTIVITY_COUNT = 0 THEN RUN SQL 1     ----- if records are present then run sql 1

ELSE 

RUN SQL 2    ----- if records are not present the run sql 2
```

Could you please suggest a TERADATA SQL CODE ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You have the logic.  Assuming Activity_Count is a count of records.  Look up how to get a count into a SQL variable.  Then use the logic you have shown us.  You are on the right track.

Comment: @jasttim do you know Teradata sql syntax which will run the first if statement? I will use that twice then. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Which client are you using? BTEQ & SQL Assistant support that, otherwise you need a Stored Procedure.

Comment: SQL Assistant @dnoeth

Comment: How can I do that in SQL Assistant? Could you give me an example code, please? @dnoeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Assistant supports old BTEQ syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COL1 > 0;

.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN .GOTO l2; -- no result, skip SQL 1

SQL 1     ----- if records are present then run sql 1

.EXIT;  -- don't run SQL2

.LABEL l2;

SQL 2    ----- if records are not present the run sql 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE activity_proc(OUT out_res VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
  DECLARE l_cnt  int;
  SELECT n_activity_count INTO l_cnt FROM My_Table;

  IF l_cnt=0 THEN
    select  'No activity' into out_res;
  ELSE  
    select  'Activity count: ' || cast(l_cnt as varchar(10)) into out_res;
  END IF;   

END;
```

Also, keep in mind that activity_count is a reserved word.